# How to Grant Permission for Stored Procedure Access to other users?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, permissions, execute

I have created a stored procedure in T-SQL as below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_emp_dept(@eno numeric,@sal numeric OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @sal = SAL
FROM emp
WHERE EMPNO=@eno
END
```

Now, my problem is that this proc is in my database, some other user wants to access it from his database using his table data. How do I grant him the permission to use my stored procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::<dbName>.sp_emp_dept
    TO <user>;
GO

Comment: What do you mean by different database? is it in same instance?

Comment: @SaUce - yes it is in the same instance. Naveen Kumar - I tried that option, but its working.